# lock performance cloning object or not

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, locking

I have a `DataTable` that can contains a large number of `DataRows`; this `DataTable` can be accessed from several threads. Some threads can also change values into some rows. Actually there are some search functions that locks the `DataTable`, search into it using `linq` and return the expected value, something similar of:

```
lock(tableContent)
{
    var t = (from row in tableContent.AsEnumerable()
            where row[fieldName] != DBNull.Value && row.Field<T>(fieldName).Equals(someValue) select row);
    if (t.Any())
    { ... }
}
```

The question is: If I clone (locking the original) the `DataTable` and search into the cloned object, will the locked period be faster than searching directly into the original?

I think that the Cloning operation will take O(n) to copy each row, so the time will be the same as the search, but I don't know if there is some optimizations (memory copy, ...) that reduces the Cloning time or something similar.

Comment: I dont see a real question here!!! I think you shoud try doing it, which gives you the idea

Comment: not yet, to try this I have to spend lot of effort (the application is huge) and I will try only if some improvement is probable

Comment: You have any reason to `lock` when searching? I can understand that as you say some function may change the values. I think locking is needed only when you modifing.

Comment: Yes, other thread can add/modify/remove rows from the table. And the enumeration cannot continue if the collection is modified.

Comment: Do you need to perform both search/change parally?

Comment: If it is creating a clone will give you an incorrect reults!!!

Comment: if modifcations are very rare in comparison to reads then I think cloning/copying makes sense (the "copy-on-write" where lock acquired only on modifications but read/search is lock-free ). If writes are often, the read-write locks might be preferable.

Comment: I think that the writes can be a bit more than read, or very similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clone is O(n), but that doesn't tell the full story. A clone can be a shallow clone (just copy the references in the table) or a deep clone (copy the objects themselves). A deep clone can be a very expensive operation. Searching time can vary, too, from a quick search that checks just a single integer field, to a complex search that compares multiple values and is pretty expensive. In addition, if your data is sorted on the field that you're searching, then search is O(log n), which will be considerably faster than O(n).

If you need to take into account the possibility that somebody will add, modify, or delete rows, then you either have to lock or clone. If you're doing a single search, then cloning doesn't really make sense because you'd have to lock the table in order to clone it. And cloning will most likely take longer than searching, unless your searches are unusually expensive.

You say that modifications are rare and searches are frequent. In that case, I would suggest that you use a reader-writer lock, which will support an unlimited number of readers, or one writer. In .NET, you probably want the [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx). Using that, your code would look like this:

```
private ReaderWriterLockSlim tableLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

public bool Search(string s)
{
    tableLock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        // do the search here
        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        tableLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

Any number of readers can be searching the table concurrently. Provided, of course, that they don't modify it. If you want to modify the table, you have to acquire the write lock:

```
public void Modify(string s)
{
    tableLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        // do the modification here
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        tableLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

When a thread tries to enter the write lock, it has to wait for all existing readers to exit. Readers that come in after the write lock was requested have to wait for the existing readers to exit, and for the writer to acquire and then release the lock.

The reader/writer lock works really well for me in situations similar to the one you described: frequent reads and infrequent writes. It's worth looking into, if nothing else because it's so easy to test.

The reader/writer lock still works well if searches and updates are approximately equal because it still allows multiple readers when possible. Come to think of it, it even works well if writes are much more frequent, again because it will allow multiple reads when possible. I almost always use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` when I have a data structure that can be searched and updated.

There are other solutions, but they involve custom data structures that can be much more difficult to implement and maintain. I'd suggest you give the reader/writer lock a try. If after that, profiling shows that threads are still waiting on the lock and slowing your application's response time, you can look into alternatives.

I'm a little concerned, though, that you're doing more than just searching. Your sample selects a bunch of rows and then you do `if (t.Any()) { ... }`. Just what are you doing in that `{ ... }`? If that takes a long time, you might be better off making your code clone just the rows that you select. You can then release the lock and party on the result set to your heart's content without affecting other threads that need to access the data structure.

Comment: +1: I agree. This is one of those rare times where a RWL probably is a good route.